# Regex capture point surrounded by numbers

Tags: regex

I have this pretty complex Regex selection that almost works. I just seem to have a problem with understanding how non capture groups work. I've read the wiki but still can't seem to grasp how to use them properly (or this is the wrong usecase?)

`\b(?:[0-9]+) ?(\.) ?(?:[0-9]+)(?! ?(uur|(u|h)))\b`

If I have the following set of statements, I would like ONLY the '.' of the first 4 to be selected. ATM the Regex captures the numbers + the '.' of the first 4.

```
0.22
15.48
8.50
048948.00000 
05:23 uur
06.35 u
15.48u
0.55u
11.00h
5.54 uur
23: 31
08 :40 uur
```

I've read (and tried) to use the non capture group but it doesn't seem to help much.

Anyone have an idea on how to achieve this and care to explain a bit why it works?

Also not sure if this helps but I got a link to test the Regex I made: https://regexr.com/5dc6q

Comment: You already capture the dot in group 1. See the group in green https://regex101.com/r/aOiocK/1 You could shorten it a bit to `\b[0-9]+ ?(\.) ?[0-9]+(?! ?(uur|[uh]))\b` as you can omit the non capturing groups.

Comment: Use `\b(?:[0-9]+) ?\K\.(?= ?(?:[0-9]+)(?! ?(uur|(u|h)))\b)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mTD6Fd/1).

Comment: @Thefourthbird This seems to work indeed!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew same as thefourthbird, this seems to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\b[0-9]+ ?\K\.(?= ?[0-9]+(?! ?(?:uur|[uh]))\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mTD6Fd/2)

**Regex details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[0-9]+ ?` - one or more digits and then an optional space
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?= ?[0-9]+(?! ?(?:uur|[uh]))\b)` - a location immediately followed with

  - `?` - an optional space
  - `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
  - `(?! ?(?:uur|[uh]))` - not followed with an optional space, `uur` or `u` or `h`
  - `\b` - word boundary

Comment: This is easier to match a single dot ++